# Removing feature class or table from TOC using C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, feature-layer

What I want to achieve is to remove specific layers from the TOC either based on their array place [n] or their name (which would be ideal in case their place in the TOC changed).

The only thing I can find is the ClearLayers() method to clear all of the layers from the TOC.

Also I am aiming to remove a featurelayer and a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code and it works.........

```
private void OUT(string line)
{
            IMap Map;
            IMxDocument mxDocument;
            IApplication App = ArcMap.Application;
            mxDocument = (IMxDocument)(App.Document);
            Map = mxDocument.FocusMap;

            var pDelLayerLine = (IFeatureLayer)Map.get_Layer(0);

            IWorkspaceFactory pWorkSpaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace (IFeatureWorkspace)pWorkSpaceFactory.OpenFromFile
                (@"C:\HER YOU MUST TO DEFINE THE PATH OF YOUR FEATURE......gdb", 0);

            int x = Map.LayerCount;

            for (int i = 0; (i < x); i++)
            {
                if (Map.get_Layer(i).Name == linea)
                {
                    pDelLayerLine = (IFeatureLayer)Map.get_Layer(i);
                }
            }
            mxDocument.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(pDelLayerLine);
            mxDocument.UpdateContents();
            mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();
}
```

I hope it will helps.....

Comment: This isn't working and I think the reason is because 
1. a table isn't a feature class and 2. I'm trying to remove an xy event layer which wouldn't be in the gdb, it is only in memory

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way to iterate through layers, look at [Map.Layers(UID,True)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Layers_Property/001200000m9t000000/) as [IEnumLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnumLayer_Interface/001200000482000000/)... this limits your layer types (IFeatureLayer, IRasterLayer..) and looks in your group layers.

```
UID pUID = new UIDClass();
pUID.Value = "{40A9E885-5533-11d0-98BE-00805F7CED21}"; // IFeatureLayers

IEnumLayer pMapLayers = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.get_Layers(pUID, true);
ILayer pThisLayer = pMapLayers.Next();
while (pThisLayer != null)
{
    // not really necessary but I'll include this anyway
    if (pThisLayer.Valid)
    {
            if (pThisLayer.Name == "Layer name that I'm expecting")
            {
                ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(pThisLayer); 
            }
            // but what about from a particular database?
            IFeatureLayer pFtLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pThisLayer;
            IWorkspace pWS = (pFtLayer.FeatureClass as IDataset).Workspace;
            if (pWS.PathName == "Remove from this path")
            {
                ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(pThisLayer);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        // datasource not valid, remove anyway
        ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(pThisLayer); 
    }
    pThisLayer = pMapLayers.Next();
}
ArcMap.Document.UpdateContents(); //update the TOC
ArcMap.Document.ActivatedView.Refresh(); // refresh the view
```

There's a few techniques for working with layers that should help you in your coding. By supplying the UID you ensure that only [IFeatureLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000) are enumerated, [ILayer.valid](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Valid_Property/001200000770000000/) will tell you if the datasource is valid (or not, with red exclamation mark) and a little simple way of finding the workspace from a layer...

Note: you can delete layers in this enumeration and still continue as the indices are still valid. If you use `for (I = 0;I < Map.LayerCount;I++)` then when you remove a layer you straight away break the index and skip the next layer. If you must use simple iteration then you have to use `for (I=Map.LayerCount;I>-1;I--)` to iterate, reverse order doesn't break the index.

Answer (score 2):

With a little modification, I got this to work.

This is important to note that this is for feature layers only, not tables.

```
        IMap map;
        IMxDocument mxDocument;
        mxDocument = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
        map = mxDocument.FocusMap;
        mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();

        IFeatureLayer featureLayer;
        featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)map.Layer[0]; // 1) Get a FeatureLayer

        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory;
        workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();


        int x = map.LayerCount;
        for (int i = 0; (i < x); i++)
        {
            if (map.get_Layer(i).Name == name)
            {
                featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)map.get_Layer(i);
            }
        }

        mxDocument.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(featureLayer);
        mxDocument.UpdateContents();
        mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: You can improve this code further, you create a workspacefactory but never use it, delete that code.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.  Do you have any idea how to remove a table by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a table from the TOC you would use the interface `IStandAloneTableCollection`.

So in VB code would go something like:

```vb
dim pSTC as IStandAloneTableCollection
pSTC = pMap
dim pST as IStandaloneTable
pST =pSTC.StandaloneTable(x) ' x is index number
pSTC.RemoveStandaloneTable(pST)
```